# How to run spring boot with local dependent projects outside eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm using spring boot 3.2.0 with Maven, currently I'm running everything inside eclipse which is working fine. But now I want to run the application from outside using command line interface (using bash in Macbook) while using eclipse only for writing code. Is it possible? I have few dependent projects which are also from the same workspace and the main project relies on them. I tried using `mvnw spring-boot:run` but it doesn't work. Spring is complaining about the dependent project (which is in the workspace) is not found.
Should I run it differently?
Below is the error I'm getting when running from commandline. Basically it is complaining about the dependency **user-service-client** version 1.0. It is only present in my workspace and not in the maven repository yet.

```
Failed to execute goal on project mainweb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mainweb:mainweb:war:1.0: Could not find artifact com.service:user-service-client:jar:1.0 in artifact-registry (https://xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx-repo)
```

Comment: What do you mean by workspace? Do you have a multi module setup? Why not trying `mvn clean verify` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I think the "workspace" is an Eclipse workspace.

Comment: OP. If you added a library in Eclipse, that will be available as a Maven dependency. You need to add the dependency in pom.xml. It's difficult to provide a solution without knowing your project structure and the error. Please [edit] your post and add the error message.

Comment: @khmarbaise it is eclipse workspace.

Comment: As @seenukarthi already wrote add that to the pom file that's the truth in a Maven build *NOT* the IDE...